# Object variable isn't updated inside a method

Tags: typescript, pass-by-reference

I am trying to update an object passed as a parameter to a method in my typescript code, but it never changes:

```
export class MyClass {

  //...
  myMethod(array) {
    //...
    let myVariable: MyObject;
    array.forEach(currentElement => {
      if (someCondition) {
        this.replaceVariable(myVariable, currentElement);
      }
    });

    console.log(myVariable); // myVariable here is Undefined

    return myVariable;
  }

  private replaceVariable(variableToReplace: MyObject, newValue: MyObject) {
    if (variableToReplace == null) {
      variableToReplace = newValue;
    } else {
      if (someCondition) {
        variableToReplace = newValue;
      }
    }

    console.log(variableToReplace); // variableToReplace here is replaced by newValue
  }
}
```

As objects are always passed by reference, I was expecting that `myVariable` gets the new value after calling the method `replaceVariable`. But as you can see in the code comments, the variable is replaced inside the `replaceVariable` method, and keeps an `undefined` value in `myMethod`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As objects are always passed by reference, I was expecting that myVariable gets the new value after calling the method replaceVariable

Yes they are passed by reference. However they are *not* passed as *out* varaibles. You can mutate, but you cannot reassign.

## Difference

Since JavaScript doesn't have support for *out* variables, here is a C# reference for the two so you can understand the difference:

- Ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref
- Out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I ended up returning the value from the `replaceVariable` method and assigning it to the variable instance `myVariable`

Comment: Perfect choice 